# is there a max number of rows in a SQL Server 2008/2012 and MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Im evaluating a RDBMS for a bank app solution and i need to be sure about these performance parameter. There is a lot of info on internet that is confusing me :O.

1. Max number of concurrent connections per instance.
2. Max number of records per table (if there is exist a limit).
3. Max number of transactions per second.

Every suggestion it will be welcome

Comment: 3) is impossible to answer because it depends on gazillion variables in your system

Comment: MySQL:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits

Comment: For #1:  A _practical_ limit for MySQL 5.7 is 48-64.  For #2:  No limit on _rows_, but limit on _bytes_; let's say that a Petabyte would be trick to exceed, but possible.  For #3: Over a million TPS has been demonstrated; but don't expect to get that.

Comment: You will probably encounter _hardware_ limitations before database limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has excellent documentation on the [limitations of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

MySQL has a [similar resource](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-reslimits-excerpt-5.1-en.pdf) (warning - PDF) on their site.

As it stands, your question is far to broad and will likely be put on hold until you can narrow down your requirements.

Comment: Caution -- the MySQL pdf is a decade old and applies to an EOL'd version.  The answers to question 2 are probably still valid.

Comment: In particular, it fails to explain how to get past the 64TB limit in InnoDB.  (InnoDB is the Engine the OP must use for a "bank app".)